# AWS GET APIs work on Android Studio app but POST APIs don't. Why would POST be the issue?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This snippet should connect to the API send a request and receive a response

```
               try {

                    URL url = new URL("https://API_URL");
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    con.setDoOutput(true);
                    con.setDoInput(true);
```

Here I should be writing the API request's body

```
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                            new BufferedOutputStream(con.getOutputStream()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                    writer.write(("user="+getUsername));
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
```

Here I should be reading

```
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    String decodedString = in.readLine();
                    con.getResponseCode();
```

This is the error I get:

```
2022-05-03 01:48:04.508 13190-13190/com.example.pldb W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: API_URL
2022-05-03 01:48:04.508 13190-13190/com.example.pldb W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:255)
2022-05-03 01:48:04.508 13190-13190/com.example.pldb W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:211)
2022-05-03 01:48:04.508 13190-13190/com.example.pldb W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
2022-05-03 01:48:04.508 13190-13190/com.example.pldb W/System.err:     at com.example.pldb.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:64)
2022-05-03 01:48:04.508 13190-13190/com.example.pldb W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
2022-05-03 01:48:04.508 13190-13190/com.example.pldb W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
2022-05-03 01:48:04.508 13190-13190/com.example.pldb W/System.err:     at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
2022-05-03 01:48:04.508 13190-13190/com.example.pldb W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
2022-05-03 01:48:04.508 13190-13190/com.example.pldb W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
2022-05-03 01:48:04.508 13190-13190/com.example.pldb W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
2022-05-03 01:48:04.508 13190-13190/com.example.pldb W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
2022-05-03 01:48:04.508 13190-13190/com.example.pldb W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
2022-05-03 01:48:04.509 13190-13190/com.example.pldb W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2022-05-03 01:48:04.509 13190-13190/com.example.pldb W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
2022-05-03 01:48:04.509 13190-13190/com.example.pldb W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

On the contrary, when I use a normal GET method API, it works normally.

Comment: what data are you trying to post?

Comment: It is a simple select query that checks if the username exist. If it does exist it shall return the same user name.
(I know it doesn't make sense)

Comment: you said the issue is when you use POST request, but a POST request requires data to be posted... are you trying to post json data? You mentioned 'Here I should be writing the API's query parameters' - this doesn't make any sense. What do you mean by writing the query parameters?

Comment: I'm mistaken sorry... I meant the body of the request

Comment: what is your username value? it could be breaking the url

Comment: kirolos... that's it XD